# Python Selenium find and click multiple elements

Tags: python, selenium

I saw similar questions, but didn't find them helpful for this basic case. Please let me know if an answer exists already.

This works:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(start_url)
time.sleep(3)
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(string(), "my search text")]')
target.click()
```

This doesn't:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(start_url)
time.sleep(3)
targets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[contains(string(), "my search text")]')
for target in targets:
    target.click()
```

I get the error message

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I understand the error message, but couldn't fix it. `targets` looks like this

```
[{'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'f23eba0d-cc6d-3a43-9fce-f2ad47bd549d'}, 
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '34afe1f2-1355-6f4a-80fe-1003287e9b68'},
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '10daa515-75ad-1749-a3c9-fe82fd8c4464'},
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '14f92352-7ab9-e346-b8cb-2a1b3a5a622f'},
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '473a12b1-7739-9f40-9089-0a85c0c80dbf'},
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '990aceb7-4090-ef4b-8ed9-58a7dea66388'},
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '7b21585a-0bdd-cc47-b2ae-dd100ba4f6da'},
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '6ecda3e0-82d9-1c44-b848-f32adaea5df6'},
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'd8394f7b-3c3d-b242-9b44-465de8db15c5'},
 {'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'e496bb96-f0a4-b647-8a04-a7f364eebb53'}]
```

In comparison, this is how `target`  looks like in the first example, which works:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="ba59bda2-535e-514e-86af-4e1808b5dea4", element="93458948-946c-684e-8f90-410bf67f4be5")>
```

Comment: And how your `target` looks like when defined as `target = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(string(), "my search text")]')`?

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: is there any other code apart from this, it seems like everything is correct with this code. Also `target` and `targets` doesn't match. could you run your code using different variable names.

Comment: Hm... no this is the setup. Why does `find_elements_by_xpath` return a `dict` instead of `FirefoxWebElement` objects?

Comment: This indeed is strange, since you would expect `targets` to be a `list` of `WebElement` objects. It's a long shot, but perhaps you can try using a different webdriver? It's the webdriver that returns the objects after all.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think Gaurang is right. When I completely isolate the code, it works. There is something wrong in some other part of the code. Will try and track down.

Answer (score 0):

### **try to find the messy value in your list,Dict**

I had the same issue as I wanted to unfollow all my interests on my LinkedIn account.

when I tried companies[0] it returned 0 but for other it was returning

<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="f9936876-33b8-4beb-b244-09e9c0d4bde4", element="57ab7d78-0a2a-4f73-8caf-a9250e4fbec1")>

so I guessed the problem was in that value of my list and it may caused the error after I sliced the list as following

### companies1 = companies[1:839]

for company in companies1:
company.click()

it gone, try to find the messy value in your list by looping through it.

Comment: first element of my list was null or empty, try to find it by looping through whole your list,Dict and comparing it by ( == 0 )  to become sure that your list don't contain any of them